# Creating a Dictionary from File

Tags: python, list, function, dictionary

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reading a File into a Dictionary And Keeping Count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13115214/reading-a-file-into-a-dictionary-and-keeping-count)

I am trying to create a dictionary with two values: the first value is the text:

```
<NEW ARTICLE>
Take a look at 
what I found.
<NEW ARTICLE>
It looks like something
dark and shiny.
<NEW ARTICLE>
But how can something be dark
and shiny at the same time?
<NEW ARTICLE>
I have no idea.
```

and the second value is the count of how many times the word "ARTICLE>" is used.

I tried different methods and one method I received this error:

The erorr I receive is this:

```
(key, val) = line.split()
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
```

I've tried a few different methods but to no avail, one method I tried said it gave too many values to unpack..

I want to be able to search for a key/word in the dictionary later on and find its appropriate count.

Using Python 3.

Comment: You asked the same question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13115214/reading-a-file-into-a-dictionary-and-keeping-count). It's generally not a good idea to ask the same question repeatedly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should do it:

```
>>> with open("data1.txt") as f:
...     lines=f.read()
...     spl=lines.split("<NEW ARTICLE>")[1:]
...     dic=dict((i,x.strip()) for i,x in enumerate(spl))
...     print dic
... 
{0: 'Take a look at \nwhat I found.',
 1: 'It looks like something\ndark and shiny.',
 2: 'But how can something be dark\nand shiny at the same time?',
 3: 'I have no idea.'}
```

Comment: Hmm, I keep getting an empty dictionary when I print, I'm using Python 3.

Comment: @Goose just tested this on python 3.x, it works fine.

Comment: It works, but the concept is a bit tricky for a novice to wrap my head around, can you explain what "dic=dict((i,x.strip()) for i,x in enumerate(spl))" does exactly in your answer? Then I can choose it as correct.

Comment: @Goose `lines.split("<NEW ARTICLE>")` actually split the lines at points `wherever`it finds `"<NEW ARTICLE>"`, and returns a list like `['\nTake a look at \nwhat I found.\n', '\nIt looks like something\ndark and shiny.\n', '\nBut how can something be dark\nand shiny at the same time?\n', '\nI have no idea.\n']` , and `1[:]` was used to remove the first element from this list which is an empty string.

Comment: @Goose now the next step is simple, in that we just iterate over the list using `enumerate()` as it returns the index as well as the item from the list, so using that data we create a `dict` using `dict()`.
where `key` is the `index` and the `value` is the `item`.

Comment: that's because the dictionary doesn't have any keys named `'shiny'`, it'll raise a `KeyError`.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you don't have an empty line somewhere:

```
if newdoc == True and line != "ARTICLE>" and line:
    (key, val) = line.split()
```

(an empty line would be splitted as `[]`, which cannot be parsed as a tuple with two elements...)

Comment: There's another problem: `line != "ARTICLE>"` will always be true.

Comment: but if `line==""`, the condition will not be satisfied.

Comment: True, but none of his lines are exactly the same as `"ARTICLE>"`, so the code will certainly not work. Perhaps `not line.endswith("ARTICLE>")`...